# How can we Export Data from dataTable to pdf,Html,txt,xls from c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

How can we export the data from Datatable to dataTable to pdf,Html,txt,xls

Comment: If you want to implement something yourself, you'd might start with CSV

Comment: csv i have done, but i need to convert them to  pdf,Html,txt